# Kibana Discover is not working after deleted all indices and adding new indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, visualization, kibana-5

I ran the following command to delete all indices to see changes on the Kibana:

**`$ curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_all`**

after this operation, Kibana being not visualized Data. It is not working anymore.

I extracted new kibana folder and set up again all configuration and see the indices on the Dev Tools tab. But These indices are not showing in Discover tab.[image]

Sefa.

Comment: By deleting `_all` you've also deleted the `.kibana` index in which Kibana stores its data.

Comment: Restart the `Kibana`. It will create a brand new `.kibana` index and you Kibana should work properly.

Comment: @Val I added .kibana index in Dev Tools consoel but didn't work.

Comment: The `.kibana` index needs to be created by Kibana itself, not manually. You probably need to set up your Kibana again from scratch.

Comment: .kibana index has created by Kibana itself but still it is not working! i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate your index pattern under *Management* -> *Index Patterns* — see the [documentation for index patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html).

Your index should be `logstash-*` and the timestamp value `@timestamp` in the dropdown.

Comment: I am using Kibana 5.4 and it is not showing @timestam, when i try to create logstash-* index.

Comment: Then you probably don't have that value. Any other timestamps you can select in the dropdown? Otherwise show the mapping in your original question: GET /logstash-2017-06-01/_mapping

Answer (score 0):

To get better understanding of your problem open the page in the console of your web browser. You will see the error as "some default index not found"
Kibana always loads on a default index. You have eliminated even that pattern.
So set the default index patter again and you will be good to go

Comment: i didn't see any Error on the console tab.